# How do I ignore a specific table id when running a responsive table script

Tags: javascript

We had tables that were not looking great on mobile. I found and implemented a great script that makes tables responsive without having to edit dozens of pages and table id's to trigger. But, one particular table `<table id="amazon-polly-audio-table">` I do NOT want modified and because the formatting is already responsive. It also gives an Uncaught error. How do I *exclude* a table id? Thanks.

```html
/* Credits:
 This bit of code: Exis | exisweb.net/responsive-tables-in-wordpress
 Original idea: Dudley Storey | codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Geprd */
  
var headertext = [];
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("thead");
var tablebody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");

for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
 headertext[i]=[];
 for (var j = 0, headrow; headrow = headers[i].rows[0].cells[j]; j++) {
   var current = headrow;
   headertext[i].push(current.textContent);
   }
} 

for (var h = 0, tbody; tbody = tablebody[h]; h++) {
 for (var i = 0, row; row = tbody.rows[i]; i++) {
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[h][j]);
   } 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding `id` to `thead` & `tbody` and then use `not` selector

```
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("thead:not([id='amazon-polly-audio-table-thead'])");
var tablebody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody:not([id='amazon-polly-audio-table-tbody'])");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! The id is not on the thead or tbody. It's on the <table id> tag which is not in this script at all. How do I add ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may find you want to repeat this behavior for other tables in the future, so   consider using a class like "ignoreResponsive" and add it to the table instead of just targeting a specific element ID.

```
<table class="ignoreResponsive">
```

Then in your script, add a new selector to get only tables without that class.

```js
/* Credits:
 This bit of code: Exis | exisweb.net/responsive-tables-in-wordpress
 Original idea: Dudley Storey | codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Geprd */
  
var headertext = [];
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("thead");
var tablebody = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");

/* selector to get just the tables without the class ignoreResponsiove */
var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table:not(.ignoreResponsive"));

/* wrap whole thing in loop that just does tables you want from the selector */
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {

  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headertext[i]=[];
    for (var j = 0, headrow; headrow = headers[i].rows[0].cells[j]; j++) {
      var current = headrow;
      headertext[i].push(current.textContent);
      }
  } 

  for (var h = 0, tbody; tbody = tablebody[h]; h++) {
    for (var i = 0, row; row = tbody.rows[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[h][j]);
      } 
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! The id is not on the thead or tbody. It's on the <table id> tag which is not in this script at all. How do I add ? Thanks!

Comment: @CarlRodriguez I've updated my answer to more correctly address the issue.